# Proving that horizontal sums are equivalent to vertical sums.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I want to show the following result:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{k_n} a_{n,m}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=n_m}^{\infty} a_{n,m} $$

where $(k_n)$ is subsequence of $\mathbb{N}$, $n_m$ is the smalllest natural number such that $k_n\geq m$, and $a_{n,m}\in [0,\infty]$ for all $n,m$. Geometrically the LHS corresponds to row sums of an infinite matrix while the RHS corresponds to column sums.

My idea is to use the following two results for nonnegative series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n =\sup \bigg\{ \sum_{n\in F} a_n :  F \text{ finite}, F\subset \mathbb{N}\bigg \}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}  a_{n,m} =\sup \bigg\{ \sum_{(n,m)\in F} a_{n,m} :  F \text{ finite}, F\subset \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \bigg \}$$

The first result implies that the LHS can be written

$$\sup \bigg\{ \sum_{n\in F} \sum_{m=1}^{k_n} a_{n,m} :  F \text{ finite}, F\subset \mathbb{N}\bigg \}$$

For the RHS we may define $b_{n,m}=a_{n_m+n-1,m}$ for $(n,m) \in  \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ so that, using the second result, it reads

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  b_{n,m} =\sup \bigg\{ \sum_{(n,m)\in F} b_{n,m} :  F \text{ finite}, F\subset \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \bigg \}$$

Let $F\subset \mathbb{N}$ be finite and $P:=\{(n,m): n\in F, 1\leq m\leq k_n\}$. Let $M:=\max\{k_n : n\in F \}$ and $N:=\max\{k_n-n_m+1: (n,m) \in P\}$. Then $F':=\{1,\dots,N\}\times \{1,\dots,M\}$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ and

$$\sum_{n\in F} \sum_{m=1}^{k_n} a_{n,m}\leq \sum_{(n,m)\in F'} b_{n,m}$$

Indeed if $(n,m)\in P$ then $m\leq k_n$ and so $n_m\leq n\leq k_n$ by definition of $n_m$. Then $a_{n,m}=b_{n-n_m+1,m}$ with $(n-n_m+1,m)\in F'$ so $a_{n,m}$ appears as a term in the right sum. As $F$ is arbitrary we deduce that LHS$\leq$RHS.

Conversely let $F\subset \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} $ be finite, $N:=\max\{n_m+n-1 : (n,m)\in F \text{ for some } m\}$ and $M:=\max\{m : (n,m)\in F \text{ for some } n\}$. As $k_n \to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$ there exist some natural number $M'$ such that $ k_{M'}\geq M$. Define $N':=\max\{N,M'\}$.Then $F':=\{1,\dots, N'\}$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ and

$$\sum_{(n,m)\in F} b_{n,m} \leq \sum_{n\in F'} \sum_{m=1}^{k_n} a_{n,m}$$

Indeed if $(n,m)\in F$ then $n_m+n-1 \leq N'$ and $m\leq k_{N'}$. Hence $b_{n,m}=a_{n_m+n-1,m}$ appears as a term in the right sum. As $F$ is arbitrary we deduce that RHS$\leq $LHS.

Is this OK? Is there a more efficient to go about this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What guarantees that the sums converge or that the suprema exist?

Comment: @Its_me The supremum is understood in the extended real-valued sense. It always exist in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$. I don't exclude the case that the series sum be $\infty$.

Comment: I assume $(k_n)$ is an increasing sequence, isn't it? Since all $a_{n,m}$ are positive both series (i.e. the sums) are convergent iff they are absolutely convergent. If a series is absolutely convergent, then the sum is independent of the order in which terms are summed. Thus, if they converge, then to the same limit point.

Comment: @Its_me Right $(k_n)$ is strictly increasing. You are right the result is analogous to the rearrangement theorem for absolutely convergent series. However here we are dealing with double series and the indexing is nested.

Comment: @Its_me Could you write the details for how to do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: For double series absolute convergence guarantees that all modes of convergence -- by rows, columns, squares, diagonals, etc. are equivalent.